# Filter emails based on attachment count

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How to filter for emails that has an x amount of attachments or more than an x amount of attachments?

It easy to filter outlook emails for emails that has an attachment as `hasattachments:yes`, but I need only emails with multiple attachments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do that. But you can go another way. What you need to do is to create a VBA macro that will iterate through your emails and set some custom property to the number of attachment in a message. After that you'll be able to search your emails using this custom property.